# Load single div in a UIWebView

Tags: xcode, html, uiwebview

I've searched quite a few on the internet but I wasn't able to find an answer so I'd like to ask to you if there's a way to load just one div of a web page in a UIWebView. I think that I should use some injected js but I've no idea about how to do that.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. You want to include a div from a website - just the one. Now you could download the HTML and pull it apart and insert the div you want as raw HTML to the webview. This will have the effect of stripping all the styles and such from the website you're taking it from. You will just get the raw HTML. If you want it with all the style and such in tact then you need to do come clever javascript/jquery injection and hide/show relevant elements to your liking. Could be tricky. What do you want it for specificially?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd prefer to keep all the styling, but if displaying raw HTML is easier it's still okay (then I could inject CSS in the webView, isn't it?). In my case I need to display different divs from different pages many times so I also need something pretty fast...